# DesktopAppConverter can't convert exe

Tags: windows, uwp, desktop-app-converter

I'm trying to use the DesktopAppConverter to convert an .EXE package into UWP compatible executable so I can publish on Windows Stores.

The exe package is compiled from Unity3D for standalone.

When I use the convert command I get an error.

> DesktopAppConverter.exe -Installer .\eve.exe -Destination .\Converted
> -PackageName "eve" -Publisher "CN=C9839D08-E518-4B7C-BA6C-FCA61493C7F3" -Version 1.0.0.0 -MakeAppx

```
C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_x64__8wekyb3d8bbwe\DesktopAppConverter.ps1 : Exception calling "Compile" with "0" argument(s): "Reference
to undeclared attribute group 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/preview/windows10/msixappcompatsupport:PreviewEntryPointAttributesGroup'."
At line:1 char:1
+ &'C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\Microsoft.DesktopAppConverter_2.1.4.0_ ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,DesktopAppConverter.ps1
```

I would appreciate the help , I tried looing online but couldn't find a solution.

Comment: When you use DesktopAppConverter to convert exe, there are some restrictions on packaging application. This issue might be caused by unsupported desktop application. You can read [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/desktop/desktop-to-uwp-prepare) to check whether the application exclude unsupported condition .

Answer (score 1):

The DesktopAppConverter is Microsoft's first try at building a tool for converting older packages to MSIX/APPX.

They deprecated it and instead released the [MSIX Packaging Tool](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/msix-packaging-tool.html). I included a link that teaches you how to use this tool to convert your package, give it a try.

If this still does not work, you can use the free [Express edition from Advanced Installer.](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/express) This was released in a partnership with Microsoft before they built their own solution (the MSIX Packaging Tool).